# How can I put (IF)condition in my SQL code?

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement

I need to put (IF) condition in my code to show only the datediff bigger than 0  but always happen error , anybody can help me please ?

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(`Date` ,CURDATE()) AS Date,`id` AS Dateid
FROM `election`
ORDER BY `Date` ASC
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WreNi.png)

i need only Date bigger than 0

Comment: Show us sample data and the error message you received.

Comment: There's no IF in the SQL language. Use WHERE/AND/OR/CASE.

Comment: @jarlh http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html ? Though the rest of the comment seems right on.

Comment: @jarlh how ? can u fix it for me i need to show datediff bigger than 0

Comment: @jarlh you sure about that? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/if.html

Comment: @JonStirling, seems like MySQL has `IF()`... (Which is not an if statement.)

Comment: Error
SQL query: Documentation


SELECT IF((DATEDIFF(`Date` ,CURDATE()))>0) AS Date,`id` AS Dateid FROM `election` ORDER BY `Date` ASC
 LIMIT 0, 25 
MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ') AS Date,`id` AS Dateid FROM `election` ORDER BY `Date` ASC
LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1

Comment: @Takarii, I thought I was... At least ANSI SQL has no if().

Comment: @Takarii i need to show datediff bigger than 0 ? how can i do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not very pretty, but you can just recreate the date field in the `where` clause to compare it:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(`Date` ,CURDATE()) AS Date,`id` AS Dateid
FROM `election`
WHERE DATEDIFF(`Date` ,CURDATE()) > 0
ORDER BY `Date` ASC
```

Comment: I wouldn't worry about how pretty it looks if it does the job!